# Hilt with multi module not working with aar file

Tags: android, dagger, dagger-hilt

I've created a project with one module. e.g

```
app
module
```

When I'm using the following code in the app's `build.gradle`, It's working fine

```
implementation project(':module')
```

When I'm creating `.aar` for `module` with `minifyEnabled true` and using it in `build.gradle` using bellow code

```
implementation files('module-release.aar')
```

It gives the following error

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mypackage.DaggerMainApplication_HiltComponents_ApplicationC$ActivityRetainedCImpl$ActivityCImpl cannot be cast to com.com.mypackage.MyActivity_GeneratedInjector